# Я говорю, что(,) когда ты придёшь, я тогда смогу помочь

Tags: запятые

Нужна запятая? Думаю нет, т. к. есть слово *тогда*, которое не даёт переставить местами мини-предложения.

> Я думал, что(,) если не ставишь запятую, тебе тогда дают два с колом.

> Я говорю, что(,) когда ты придёшь, я тогда смогу помочь.

Comment: Я говорю что: когда ты придёшь, я смогу тебе помочь. Я думал, что если: не ставишь запятую тебе, тогда дают два с колом; а коли ставишь, то один дают, с кока-колом.